# Different pages same link php

Tags: php

I am working on a portal with login. 
The link for the loginpage is like this: http://www.example.com
If the user logged in the link is like this: http://www.example.com/account

Is there a way to have the same link for both pages? I thought with php include but this does not work

Comment: You could put a redirect at the top of the login page

Comment: "but this does not work"  Show what you tried that isn't working.  In what way is it not working?

Comment: After login I create a header refresh to the account.php file but this create http://www.example/com/account.php

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you determine if a user is logged in, but most would use sessions

```
if($_SESSION['loggedIN']){
//stuff for logged in user
// an include would also be fine
}else{
//stuff for not logged in user, ie login form
}
```